# Jsp page is downloaded instead of being displayed

Tags: java, jsp, parse-platform

I am using this guide https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#hosting/windows
so my website will be hosted on parse servers.

Somehow, an html page can be displayed, but if I change the extension to "jsp" instead of "html" the page is being downloaded instead of being displayed.
(If I run the jsp page on localhost with tomcat, everything works fine).
What can I do to deal also with jsp pages?

==== Edit ====

I have 3 folders in the main folder: cloud, config, public.
Inside config I have only one file called: global.json. It's content is:

```
{
  "global": {
    "parseVersion": "1.4.2"
  },
  "applications": {
    "AppName": {
      "applicationId": "Some Id",
      "masterKey": "Some Key"
    },
    "_default": {
      "link": "AppName"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the configuration file to map to jsp

Comment: I have 3 folders - cloud, config, public.
 And in config folder there is only one file - global.json- I don't see any "map" string inside this file

Comment: I only has (some) experience with hosting on Ubuntu, but you have to make the mapping somewhere... And the small thing I saw in the link you sent, was HTML... Personally I like HTML JavaScript RESTing to Java (but you weren't asking)

Comment: Did you find cause and solution for this? I am getting same error in my spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Check here: [Spring boot downloading jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138622/spring-boot-downloading-jsp-file)

Answer (score -1):

Add the required dependency inside `pom.xml` file
Go to `Maven` Repository and get the jasper dependency as per your Tomcat version.

Or Copy @DorinSimion `xml` code inside your `pom.xml` file