# Spring boot downloading jsp file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot simple application for displaying a JSP.
However instead of rendering the JSP the page gets downloaded in the browser.
Please suggest?

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tcadmin?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.username=tcuser
spring.datasource.password=tcuserpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
server.context-path=/internal
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

I have made the folder src/main/webapp and put printReciept.jsp in that.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.a2b</groupId>
    <artifactId>A2BInternalModules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>A2BInternalModules</name>
    <description>Sitemap Generator for A2B</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Tomcat Embed -->

        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>required</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

PrintRecieptController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PrinReciept", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World !!!");
        return "printReciept";
    }
```

**printReciept.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Print Receipt
</body>
</html>
```

The controller is getting hit but instead of rendering the JSP it is downloading that page in browser.Please suggest.

Comment: can you specify the location of your JSP files, is it inside WEB-INF or inside any folder in WEB-INF

Comment: inside webapp folder. I also have a copy in WEB-INF folder just to somehow run it but it downloads the page

Comment: @Yogi How does location matter here? It is getting downloaded means of course file has been found, it is not just opening in browser.

Comment: @Jeets Any solution you found? I am facing same issue. (Also, in my spring boot app there is no WEB-INF folder).

Answer (score 15):

Within Maven dependencies check the tomcat-embed version and find the relevant tomcat-jasper version dependency in the maven central. This jar is required for JSP compilation. Since it is not compiled it comes as a downloadable.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

My embed tomcat version was 9.0.19, and I got the jasper relevant for that version.

Answer (score 5):

I Got same error but i am not putting tomcat jasper who is responsible for converting our jsp files,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Just add tomcat-jasper according to you spring boot using tomcat

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the JEE dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, I highly suggest that you put all your JSP into your WEB-INF folder (this is true for any templating engine) and choose a prefix other than root. It's just more secure and more flexible if you also want to have some RESTlike endpoints served from the same application.

You can also extend the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and override applicable methods.

```
// Add the JSP view resolver.
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp();
    // OR
    registry.jsp("/",".jsp");
}
//... snip
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addViewController("/yourpath")
        .setViewName("yourtemplate");
}
```

"addViewControllers" is nice to use so you don't have to create a controller for each generic JSP and partial. Notice that I did not add ".jsp" to the view name.

You can use the root context as the prefix and still use the above configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ, try reloading maven dependency after you add a dependency for tomcat jasper. Worked for me :)

Remember to add correct version though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle, add the below dependency

```
compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if **tomcat server** version and **tomcat-embed-jasper** is mismatching.

**How to find server version?**

Incase you mention it in the pom.xml or build.gradle replace it directly.
If not check the logs for the below line and use the same version in the tomcat-embed-jasper. It should work.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
```

```
implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.60'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct version number and this dependency worked just fine for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside tomcat-embed-jasper & jstl i had to servlet-api dependency... that's worked for me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEdYS.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).