# Spring Boot + Apache Wicket - JSP pages are downloading instead of rendering

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, servlets, wicket

My application is built using Spring Boot 2.1.4 + Apache wicket and some legacy web servlet and JSP pages. But JSP pages are getting downloaded instead of rendering.

I have provided the following dependencies to compile JSP for embedded tomcat.
pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
             <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried with moving all my JSP pages to 
main/java/resources/META-INF/resources for default spring boot classpath.

Booting up the application using the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClaimIQWicketApplication 
    extends WicketBootStandardWebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        context = SpringApplication.run(ClaimIQWicketApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I expect my JSP pages should get rendered instead of download.

Please help me if anybody else has encountered such issue and found any solution.

Comment: I think you might have the same problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138622/spring-boot-downloading-jsp-file

Comment: I followed given steps in the above post but no luck. Still, JSP's are downloading instead of rendering.

Comment: Did you extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as described in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141197/8819761 ?